# How to serialize multiple objects of different types?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to serialize an array of objects and a string. This is the serialization code:

```
FileStream s;
s = new FileStream(savefile.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(s, ch.chaps);
bf.Serialize(s, txtPassword.Text);
s.Close();
```

This is the deserialization code:

```
FileStream s;
s = new FileStream(openfile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
string password = (string)bf.Deserialize(s);
ch.chaps = (Chapter[])bf.Deserialize(s);
s.Close();
int i;

if (password == txtPassword.Text)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            combChapSelect.Items.Add(ch.chaps[i].chapName);         
        }
        catch
        {
             i = 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code and visual studio says there are no errors but the openfiledialog doesn't close when I select a file and nothing happens. Have I done something wrong or is there another way to serialize different object types?

Comment: Is Chapter implementing ISerializable? You say you are trying to "serialize" but in your code you call "deserialize". So are you trying to serialize or deserialize?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this backwards.  You have to deserialize in the same order that you serialize.

In your serialization, its chaps-then-password.  In your deserialization, its password-then-chaps.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I didn't know that the order mattered.